# Python tkinter same Label called multiple times

Tags: python, tkinter, label, code-reuse

is there any way to use same label multiple times?
what I have is:

```
emptyRow = Label(frame)
```

and when I want use that empty row I call it like this:

```
emptyRow.grid(row=0)
emptyRow.grid(row=3)
```

i can only have latest call on that grid so row=0 will be ignored and row=3 will be used, any way to reuse it so I dont have to create another `emptyRow3 = Label(frame)` ?

Comment: You can not place the same widget at different locations at the same time... If you don't want to give a new name, can't you use Label(frame).grid(row=3) ?

Comment: You can also use rowconfigure to get an empty row to show --> main.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=50)  http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/pydoc/Tkinter.Grid.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

short answer: no you can't display a widget in multiple places/ create several empty labels without calling `Label(frame)` for each one.

if creating an empty label is something you do often you can make a short function to do it:

```
def fill_empty(parent,row,column):
    empty = Label(parent)
    empty.grid(row=row,column=column)
    return empty
```

but I'd highly recommend using padding instead of dummy widgets to space things out, see [this documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You may define your element as a function which returns element. It'll create a new object each time you call it:

```
emptyRow = lambda:Label(frame)

emptyRow().grid(row=0)
emptyRow().grid(row=3)
```